# Почему одно приложение возвращает access_token а другое code? [OpenAPI VK]

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, веб-программирование

Заметил интересный момент: есть 2 standalone-приложения с идентичными настройками. Но при обращении по ссылке:

```
http:/oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=12345678&‌​scope=wall,offline&response‌​_type=token&v=5.60redirect_uri=http//site.ru/
```

после авторизации меня, как и должно, редиректит на мой сайт, который я указал в redirect_uri, но вот только одно приложение отдает редирект с #access_token:

```
site.ru/#access_token=<TOKEN>
```

а другое при редиректе кидает #code:

```
site.ru/#code=<CODE>
```

Почему такое происходит с идентичными standalone-приложениями? При том, что при обращении в обоих случаях я передаю параметр **response_type=token**